# Is python not made to handle integer overflows?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, overflow, long-integer

So, I'm trying a programming puzzle, which is -> 
**(Although , what the puzzle is, has nothing to do with my question, but still if needed for some context)**

You are given a read only array of n integers from 1 to n.

Each integer appears exactly once except A which appears twice and B which is missing.

Return A and B.

I tried implementing the code in Python-3 with the same logic (only made syntactical changes) , as of the below code in C++.

```
vector<int> Solution::repeatedNumber(const vector<int> &A) {

    long long int act_sum = 0;
    long long int act_sum_sq = 0;
    long long int exp_sum;
    long long int exp_sum_sq;
    long long int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
        act_sum = act_sum + (long long int)A[i];
        act_sum_sq = act_sum_sq + (long long int)A[i]*A[i];
    }

    exp_sum = (long long int)(A.size())*(A.size()+1)/2;
    exp_sum_sq = (long long int)(A.size())*(A.size()+1)*(2*A.size()+1)/6;

    long long int diff_sum_sq = exp_sum_sq - act_sum_sq;
    long long int diff_sum = exp_sum - act_sum;

    long long int tog = diff_sum_sq/diff_sum;

    long long int mis = (tog + diff_sum)/2;
    long long int rep = mis - diff_sum;

    vector<int> sol;
    sol.push_back((int)rep);
    sol.push_back((int)mis);

    return sol;
}
```

Python code ->

```
class Solution:
    # @param A : tuple of integers
    # @return a list of integers

    def repeatedNumber(self, A):
         act_sum = 0
         act_sum_sq = 0
         exp_sum=0
         exp_sum_sq=0
         i = 0
         size=len(A)

         for i in range(size):
            act_sum = act_sum + A[i]
            act_sum_sq = act_sum_sq + A[i]*A[i]


         exp_sum = (size)*(size+1)/2
         exp_sum_sq =(size)*(size+1)*(2*size+1)/6

         diff_sum_sq = exp_sum_sq - act_sum_sq
         diff_sum = exp_sum - act_sum

         tog = diff_sum_sq/diff_sum

         mis = (tog + diff_sum)/2
         rep = mis - diff_sum



         return [int(rep),int(mis)]
```

The code written in python gives a partially correct answer on the challenge website, (and it gives the reason that the code might fail for larger test cases - like having about 2000 elements in the array)
But, 
the same code in C++ (with syntactical changes only) works absolutely fine!
why?
So, can the presence of long long int in C++ be the reason behind this?
Is python not meant for huge data sets? and if no, then how to handle overflow in python

Comment: Python integers can be any size, even a thousand bytes' worth if you wanted. Please post your Python code.

Comment: i am a bit confused. Is it possible that your question is simply "How does python handle integer overflow?" In c++ signed overflow is undefined, so I dont really understand your conclusions about the code being "fine" in c++

Comment: Also be aware that `unsigned long long int` can hold about twice as big a positive number as `long long int`.

Comment: Don't port code from language to language. It rarely works. [It doesn't even work for human communication languages.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) Languages may look similar, but they behave differently. What you need to do is understand the beaviour described by the program and implement the same behaviour in the new language according to that languages rules and idioms.

Comment: Since you are using `signed` integers, if there is any overflow you have undefined behavior. It may or may not work, and that may change at any time for no apparent reason.

Comment: Hi, I have added the python code. Both solutions although correct , but for the python code solution, I get partial points, saying, Might not work for larger test cases). Any edits that you would like to suggest on the python code ?

Comment: Start your Python interpreter and compare `3/2` to `3//2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in these lines:

```cpp
exp_sum = (long long int)(A.size())*(A.size()+1)/2;
exp_sum_sq = (long long int)(A.size())*(A.size()+1)*(2*A.size()+1)/6;
```

vs

```py
exp_sum = (size)*(size+1)/2
exp_sum_sq =(size)*(size+1)*(2*size+1)/6
```

The type of `exp_sum` in the C++ version is `long long int`. In python it is `float` (equivalent to a C++ `double`). The conversion in python happens in the division. Normal division in python3 [always returns a float](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations). You can fix your python code by using these lines instead:

```py
exp_sum =  size * (size + 1) // 2
exp_sum_sq =  size * (size + 1) * (2 * size + 1) // 6
```

With this fix, the python version should have no more limitations – unlike `C++`, python integers can hold arbitrarily large values and do never overflow.